# PLC unit power issues

Tags: programmable-logic, plc

I am creating my own PLC, just for practice with PLCs (as I am an electrical apprentice). I have bought a power supply which changes 240V AC to 24V DC. When it is connected to my PLC unit, and I read the output with my multimeter, the output just pulses, so nothing useful happens. The LEDs on the PLC unit also light up for half a second or so. However, when I disconnect the output leads and measure the output, I have a steady 24V DC output. Any ideas on what the problem is?

Comment: What is the amperage of the converter and of the PLC device? Perhaps the converter can't provide enough current.

Comment: The plc isn't currently connected to anything, thats not the issue, I've ordered the power supply and the plc exactly the same as a friends.

Comment: This sounds like the PSU  (240Vac to 24Vdc) has exceeded it's maximum output and is shutting down the output to protect it's self then starts up again. This is common PSU behaviour. It sounds like you have a short (or very high load) on the 24Vdc supply. This could be the polarity revered and a protection diode is conducting or even a stray piece of wire or the like across a terminal or track..(I've seen a spanner once just as an example..)

Answer (score 1):

I also agree with the overload theory. the next possible root cause could be a short circuit some where along the PLC or the PLC rack if any or any of the PLC input or output cards. please post the power supply, PLC make and model, and the input and output card modules that are in the PLC system rack if any. After that a check by process of elimination will discover the fault. take care!

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to know the power consumption of your PLC unit?
If the power demand be larger than the produced power of your power supply, something like what you have faced might be happening.

Comment: I had nothing hooked up, it was all koyo click, it was all compatible, I ended up buying a new one haha